# Division operation in LC-3 with the result is a real number (not integer)

Tags: division, lc3

With LC-3, we have only three operations ADD, AND, NOT. From these, we can make some algorithms to do all operations like subtraction, division,... However, the data type LC-3 allowing is 16 bit 2's complement INTEGER. So in the case that I do division, the dividend is not divisible by the divisor, yielding that the result is a real number. Does it cause an error? Thank you.

Comment: Think it further through, maybe even write it up.  If you divide, say, by repetitive subtraction, when would you stop?  What would you have when you're done?  How do you know whether it divides evenly or not, and if not what do you have left?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers

Comment: So it will return the result as an integer division?

Comment: What do you mean by "return the result"? The reason to ask is that we tend to reserve the use of the word "return" for function results, and we have not spoken about functions here.. (An integer division algorithm will obtain two results, the program may be interested in only one or the other, or potentially both.)

Comment: As you noted,  since it is just running the programmed sequence of simple AND, ADD, NOT (and branch) instructions. this processor won't know you're doing division,.  None of these instructions individually can produce an "error", so there's no way for the hardware to make an "error".  Thus, it would be up to the program/programmer to decide if there's an error, and if that choice is made, what to do upon error detection (such as end the program or print a message..)

Comment: You can also study other processors that do have integer divide and some of them will produce an error on divide-by-zero or overflow.  Here the processor's notion of error is usually very specific: such as taking a processor exception, which is a well-defined hardware mechanism to end the program by informing the operating system of the error.